# InvokeRestAPI with Azure Devops

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, google-oauth, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am continuously struggling to connect with the GCP from Azure Devops InvokeRestAPI task.
I have created a service connection with empty credentials. And created a API task in YAML file as below.

When I add the 'Authorization' in header, Devops fails to recognize it.
When I add the token w/wo Bearer in 'AuthToken', it fails with a 401 error, saying authentication error.
This is the wrror I face everytime, no matter what I do.
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),

Here is the yaml code:

```
 - job: planing_df1
    pool: server
    steps:  
      - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
        
        inputs:
          connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
          serviceConnection: 'GCPServiceConnectionBasic'
          method: 'GET'
          headers: |
            { 
              "PlanUrl": "$(system.CollectionUri)", 
              "ProjectId": "$(system.TeamProjectId)", 
              "HubName": "$(system.HostType)", 
              "PlanId": "$(system.PlanId)", 
              "JobId": "$(system.JobId)", 
              "TimelineId": "$(system.TimelineId)", 
              "TaskInstanceId": "$(system.TaskInstanceId)", 
              "AuthToken": "ya29.a0AeTM1ie8PKbCNb3nnTJ9XFnoVlBUlgiM48XAENJIFAl-dp4gHblablabla"
            }
          urlSuffix: '/myproj/locations/europe-west4/repositories/Dataform'
          waitForCompletion: 'true'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the API in Invoke Rest API task, you need to make sure that the same token can work fine on your local environment.

Then you can use the following format to set the headers of the Invoke Rest API Task.

```
"Authorization": "Bearer  bearertokendeatil "
```

For example:

```
- job: planing_df1
    pool: server
    steps:  
      - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
        
        inputs:
          connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
          serviceConnection: 'GCPServiceConnectionBasic'
          method: 'GET'
          headers: |
            { 
              "PlanUrl": "$(system.CollectionUri)", 
              "ProjectId": "$(system.TeamProjectId)", 
              "HubName": "$(system.HostType)", 
              "PlanId": "$(system.PlanId)", 
              "JobId": "$(system.JobId)", 
              "TimelineId": "$(system.TimelineId)", 
              "TaskInstanceId": "$(system.TaskInstanceId)", 
              "Authorization": "Bearer  bearertokendeatil"
            }
          urlSuffix: '/myproj/locations/europe-west4/repositories/Dataform'
          waitForCompletion: 'true'
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin for the reply. I have tried the same token and request in my local and it is working. When I add "Authorization" in the headers, this error comes up.

Exception Message: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path 'Authorization', line 10, position 2. (type JsonReaderException)

Comment: Seems like Authorization is not a valid keyword in InvokeRestAPI task

Comment: Have you tried to add the Authorization and add bearer type ? for example: `"Authorization": "Bearer  bearertokendeatil"` Test with the same header and it can work

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. Yes I have already tried and its the same error.
One of the docs in InvokeRestAPi says that it only supports Basic Authorization. (assuming its different than Bearer).

I am not sure how to generate GCP Basic token.

Comment: like this: Authorization = (Basic  base64AuthInfo)

Comment: You can try to use user name and password as Basic auth.  `"Authorization": "Basic converttobased64(username:password)" ` or you can add the user name and password in service connection GCPServiceConnectionBasic

Comment: https://www.base64encode.org/ you can convert the auth info to base64 type in this URL

Comment: I have tried using Basic "Base64 Token", but its not even working in my Postman.
So it seems like GCP doesnt support the Base token authentication?

Comment: And this is what I got when I tried with Basic in Devops
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"

Comment: From this doc: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication. It shows that GCP supports Oauth token and JWT token. They are related to bearer token

Comment: Thanks @Kevin
Yes GCP supports Bearer and it works in my local. But Devops is not allowing me to add Bearer token. I am providing token in header "AuthToken". Here I have tried both encoded and non encoded token but nothing helped.

Comment: https://www.cloudshift.nl/blog/2022/07/http-requests-in-yaml-based-pipelines Refer to this blog, the bearer token should be supported by invoke rest api task. The same as the format of my answer: `"Authorization": "Bearer  bearertokendeatil"`

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin. You saved me:)
Actually I dont know where I was going wrong but now it worked. Thanks again:)